# How to deploy Laravel Project using Laradock

Tags: laravel, deployment, laradock

I have setup the local environment of the project using Laradock and pushed the images to a Amazon ECR.

Now I'm trying to deploy that in to a EC2 instance

My Issues are :

1. Once I pull the images to the EC2 from ECR, should I include docker-composer.yml file in side of laradock folder to the EC2 or can I run the images using "docker run" command ?
2. Should I add laradock folder to remote server ?

Answer (score 1):

**Once I pull the images to the EC2 from ECR, should I include docker-composer.yml file in side of laradock folder to the EC2 or can I run the images using "docker run" command ?**

Yes you should add docker-compose.yml, because that is the file docker-compose uses to know what services exist. You should run `docker-compose up <service1> <service2> <service3> ... -d` and figure out if the configurations are working for you out of the box.

**Should I add laradock folder to remote server ?**

Yes this is where the specific images and configs are defined.

Comment: Currently the images are located at my target EC2. as (my_nginx, my_mysql, my_PHP-FPM). Should I make any change to my docker-composer.yml file ?

Comment: I personally recommend to create a new docker-compose file which just defines the services you need and you can `docker-compose up -d` without having to filter which services to use.

Comment: Okay I'll do it and let you know the outcome. thanks for the great help.

Comment: [this is an old example I made for Laravel](https://gist.github.com/thomasmoors/f86d69031de1562d55287f4a69b33137)